# AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'is_ajax'

Tags: django, ajax, xmlhttprequest

im trying to learn ajax in django but when i running this simple test i got this error and i cant find the reason,
my django version is 4.0

```
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'is_ajax'
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
def home(request):
    return render(request,'myapp/index.html')

def ajax_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "This is ajax"
    else:
        message = "Not ajax"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('ajax_test/', views.ajax_test, name='ajax_test')
]
```

**index.html**

```
<button id="btn">click me!</button>
   

<script>
  $("#btn").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "{% url 'ajax_test' %}",

      success: function () {
        console.log("done");
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log("error");
      },
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From the [Release Notes of 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#id2)

> The `HttpRequest.is_ajax()` method is deprecated as it relied on a jQuery-specific way of signifying AJAX calls, while current usage tends to use the JavaScript Fetch API. Depending on your use case, you can either write your own AJAX detection method, or use the new `HttpRequest.accepts()` method if your code depends on the client Accept HTTP header.

Even though it has been deprecated, you can create a custom function to check the request type as,

```py
def is_ajax(request):
    return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

and use anywhere in your view as,

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse


def is_ajax(request):
    return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'


def ajax_test(request):
    if is_ajax(request=request):
        message = "This is ajax"
    else:
        message = "Not ajax"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

Comment: Django documentation suggests using the following.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#id2 

request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest'

Answer (score 18):

this method should not be removed, since jQuery the most underrated library, still surviving, strongly, in many modern tutorials. hope one day they will bring it back.

And I found it weird for same version of django, after server deployment this error was reported, but never in local machine.

**if you have implemented `is_ajax` in your project, and it is largely scoped, here is a way to implement `is_ajax` to every request**

1. create a `middlewares.py` in any of your app, in my case, `common` app. (it does not matter which app you add this in, middlewares are wrapper functions called globally to perform action before or after view)

```py
class AjaxMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        def is_ajax(self):
            return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
        
        request.is_ajax = is_ajax.__get__(request)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

this will define a `is_ajax` method on every request before it is received by the view.

2. plug this in `settings.py`:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'common.middlewares.AjaxMiddleware', 
]
```

Comment: It should be 'common.middlewares.AjaxMiddleware',

Answer (score 12):

To complet the **JPG** answer based on the [release notes of 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#id2)

> **request.is_ajax()** can be reproduced exactly as **request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest'**

The `request` object used by **Django** is like [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). You can identify an AJAX request when your client use the specific header `x-requested-with` set with `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Yup this helped me out too!! Thanks