# AttributeError at /sign-up and /sign-in 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'is_ajax'

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-views, django-forms

I am getting this problem, any help will be appreciated, Im getting an arror trying to sign-in or sign-up.Error bellow.
AttributeError at /sign-up
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'is_ajax' I know that function is depreciated now, but i can't seem to fix the issue.

mixins.py

```
class AjaxFormMixin(object):

    '''
    Mixin to ajaxify django form - can be over written in view by calling form_valid method
    '''

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_invalid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            message = FormErrors(form)
            return JsonResponse({'result': 'Error', 'message': message})
        return response

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'result': 'Success', 'message': ""})
        return response
```

views.py

```
def profile_view(request):
    '''
    function view to allow users to update their profile
    '''
    user = request.user
    up = user.userprofile

    form = UserProfileForm(instance=up)

    if request.is_ajax():
        form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=up)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()
            obj.has_profile = True
            obj.save()
            result = "Success"
            message = "Your profile has been updated"
        else:
            message = FormErrors(form)
        data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
        return JsonResponse(data)

    else:

        context = {'form': form}
        context['google_api_key'] = settings.GOOGLE_API_KEY
        context['base_country'] = settings.BASE_COUNTRY

        return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)


class SignUpView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    '''
    Generic FormView with our mixin for user sign-up with reCAPTURE security
    '''

    template_name = "users/sign_up.html"
    form_class = UserForm
    success_url = "/"

    # reCAPTURE key required in context
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["recaptcha_site_key"] = settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY
        return context

    # over write the mixin logic to get, check and save reCAPTURE score
    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            token = form.cleaned_data.get('token')
            captcha = reCAPTCHAValidation(token)
            if captcha["success"]:
                obj = form.save()
                obj.email = obj.username
                obj.save()
                up = obj.userprofile
                up.captcha_score = float(captcha["score"])
                up.save()

                login(self.request, obj,
                      backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')

                # change result & message on success
                result = "Success"
                message = "Thank you for signing up"

            data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
            return JsonResponse(data)

        return response


class SignInView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    '''
    Generic FormView with our mixin for user sign-in
    '''

    template_name = "users/sign_in.html"
    form_class = AuthForm
    success_url = "/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            # attempt to authenticate user
            user = authenticate(
                self.request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(self.request, user,
                      backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
                result = "Success"
                message = 'You are now logged in'
            else:
                message = FormErrors(form)
            data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
            return JsonResponse(data)
        return response
```

I know there's a [post with similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70419441/attributeerror-wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-is-ajax), but I'm kinda struggling to fix it on my end.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

As of [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1), the [**`.is_ajax()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax) was deprecated. Indeed, in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/3.1/#id2), we see:

> The `HttpRequest.is_ajax()` method is deprecated as it relied on a jQuery-specific way of signifying AJAX calls, while current usage tends to use the JavaScript Fetch API. Depending on your use case, you can either write your own AJAX detection method, or use the new `HttpRequest.accepts()` method if your code depends on the client Accept HTTP header.

Originally, it used:

> ```
> def is_ajax():
>      return request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
> ```

But note that this is, and has always been something specific to jQuery, and therefore it makes not much sense: a browser or HTTP library can always mimic this behavior, and you can make AJAX requests without this header, and thus it is not reliable.

You can check if the browser accepts json/xml with [**`.accepts(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.accepts) which is probably what an AJAX request will try to accept, so:

```
self.request.accepts('application/json')
```

or:

```
self.request.accepts('application/xml')
```

are likely candidates for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like `if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':` everywhere so:

```py
def profile_view(request):
    '''
    function view to allow users to update their profile
    '''
    user = request.user
    up = user.userprofile

    form = UserProfileForm(instance=up)

    if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
        form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=up)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()
            obj.has_profile = True
            obj.save()
            result = "Success"
            message = "Your profile has been updated"
        else:
            message = FormErrors(form)
        data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
        return JsonResponse(data)

    else:

        context = {'form': form}
        context['google_api_key'] = settings.GOOGLE_API_KEY
        context['base_country'] = settings.BASE_COUNTRY

        return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

For class based views use it as `if self.request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':`

Comment: alright, that did help getting rid of the error, but it won't sign me up, or it won't redirect, not sure, its not giving any errors

Comment: @danielali Let me check, but I am sure if you won't check whether the request is Ajax or not, and simply use `if request.method == "POST":` it will work perfectly.

Comment: here's my repo if that'll make it easier for you https://github.com/dannyyyspam/django_google_api